# C: invoke 2 functions with same name but different packages

Tags: c, unit-testing

I want to write unit tests for my self-written standard c library.
So, i want to compare output of functions `<ctype.h>::tolower` amd my `tolower` implementation. How can i do it without renaming my functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could add a define at the start of the header of your library like this :
`#define tolower my_tolower`
Adding this pre-processor command will automatically renamed your function temporary in your files, after that in the main you only have to call my_tolower